# Do PSN games have some sort of ID number, like a barcode?

Tags: ps3, psn

I was recently building a small section which is basically a collection of video games (along with some books and movies) that I own. I was storing all these items by the UPC or ISBN number associated with it, but this only really works for physical products.

Currently, I'm just not listing PSN games because I don't really have any way to identify them. I was wondering if there *were* ID numbers such as barcodes for PSN-only games that could be found somewhere, either in the PlayStation store or on their website. For example, is there some sort of ID number for Okabu, which can only be bought and downloaded from the PlayStation Store?

Comment: All games for Sony consoles have some serial number, like ULUS-10391 (Monster Hunter Freedom Unite for PSP) or BLES-01236 (Sonic Generations for PS3). For physical games this is printed on the box. On the PSP you can find this out for digital-only games by looking at the folders on your memory stick - maybe you can view it by backing up save files to external storage on the PS3?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by building a small section? I am really confused/ intrigued by what you are doing. What confuses me is that you are storing physical items along with digital(psn games) Also, what is the purpose of storing them by upc/ isbn numbers? This just makes me too curious to let go.

Comment: @Snipe: It's just a list of stuff I own. Most of what I own is video games, so that's the focus, but I'm also listing a few books, movies, and board games. I'm not storing actual game data if that's what you're concerned about.

Comment: Oh, no. Not concerned about any data being stored, not what I was thinking. Now that you say its a list of stuff you own it makes sense to me. Still, curious as to how storing by an ID number puts the list in order, especially if its difficult to find. Personally, I'd sort them by genre then alphabetically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.nextgenupdate.com/forums/playstation-3-exploits-hacks/298929-how-find-game-id-psn-games-use-adogalogs-ps3pkg-site-find.html):

Step 1: Log on to PSN (ON YOUR COMPUTER) for the respective region you wish to find the SKU for(in the US, for example, it's us.playstation.com).

Step 2: After that search for the game you want using the search bar on left side of the screen at the bottom of the buttons. After you have found the page of the game you are looking for, hit control + u to bring up source code of the page.

Step 3: Near the bottom of the source code, you should see something like this:

```
    <meta name="hasTrailer" content=""/>
    <meta name="gameRating" content="TEEN"/>
    <meta name="partOfGame" content="Prince of Persia® Sands of Time HD"/>

    <meta name="SKU-ID" content="NPUB-30303"/>
    <meta name="last-modified" content="2010-12-27"/>
```

The second-last line of the source code is the SKU or game id of the game you were looking for (so for instance this would be NPUB30303).

Comment: This works well enough. I can't find a couple of smaller games on the PlayStation site (like Frogger Returns), but I'm fine ignoring those.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't figure it was entirely foolproof, as it requires things to have a webpage, but it was the best thing that I could find :)

Answer (score 4):

I've also recently noticed that the purchase confirmation emails (sent with every purchase) contain the ID numbers. I don't know why I've never noticed them before (probably because I just mark them as read normally). Since I've kept them all in a PlayStation Network folder on my email account, I can actually go back through some of the games that are no longer listed on the website and find their ID numbers.

> UP2054-**NPUB30373**_00-PS3ST_LIMBO00000-UG02    LIMBO (Full Game)
>
> UP2024-**NPUB30381**_00-PS3ST_SECT8PREJU-UG03    Section 8(R): Prejudice™ (Full Game)
>
> UP0001-**NPUB30163**_00-PS3STOREOUTLANDF-UG03    Outland™ (Full Game)

I suppose if you wanted, you could use that massive string as an ID, but for my use the simple `npub` ID strings suffice.